# 3060 ti giving no hdmi display output

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, troubleshooting

3060 ti slotted in a pcie 3 slot and powered by 6+2 pins. The gpu glows but fans don't spin(google said its normal) I use an hdmi to dvi adapter and it works fine on my 1650. Cmos reset and ddu didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: '6+2 pins' is your PSU capable of pushing 150W down that, because that's what the CPU night be asking for. 6-pin is only capable of 75W.

Comment: Think that might be the problem? It's one of my main guesses since fans don't spin but Iights light up

Comment: It's hard to tell from just that info & I'm by no means a rocket scientist in this field. I have a GPU in my main machine here that fakes it with two 6>8-pins… I calculated the max potential draw vs PSU theoretical output & I just get away with it. [Those last two pins tell the computer that your PSU is capable of 150W per 'plug' rather than 6-pin, which is only 75. Pull too hard, your PSU will drown.]

Comment: I have a 500 watt psu so I think it should be enough. Still, doesn't work, so psu is a potential culprit

Comment: Doesn't matter how powerful the PSU is in total [& 500 isn't much at all when you're trying to drive a high-end GPU], it's how much it can push down a single 12V rail… 6-pin plug says it can push 75W… GPU's 8-pin plug says it wants potentially 150 [otherwise it would have had a 6-pin plug instead]

Comment: Fair enough. Funnily enough I have no idea what psu I have because the pc is pre built and the psu wasn't specified so I'd have to take it apart just for a chance to figure it out

Comment: is the monitor set to use HDMI output, since you say it works with DVI?

Comment: 1650 hdmi to dvi works so I doubt that's the problem